# Testing circuit editor issue - please ignore

Tags: wire

I said please ignore :-)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8BGqg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXEtWd.png)</sup>

=====================================

## Learning to dream

In addition to specific knowledge and tinkering circuit tips, it is good to make efforts to reveal the most general ideas behind circuit phenomena. What is more, it is useful to even consider unrealistic circuit ideas... to dream. In this way, we learn not only to do but also to think and deeply understand circuit solutions.

## Conceptual transistor switch

The problem that puzzles the OP arises from the fact that ***a transistor switch is not a true digital device with two states, but an analog device with a proportional relation between the input and output quantity***. This is the simple truth about digital circuitry - ***there are no digital circuits; there are only analog circuits made to act like digital ones***. But under certain circumstances (like the ones here) they go analog again, and that can be surprising.

### Conceptual transistor

Then a transistor can be conceptually represented as a *voltage-controlled current source* (VCCS). Fortunately for us, there is such a *transconductance device* in the CircuitLab library. We just need to modify it a bit by shunting it with a backward-biased "ideal" diode D to bring it closer to a real transistor (at the end of the answer it will become more clear why).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXEtWd.png)</sup>

### Exploring the transistor switch at various RL

To turn the transistor into a switch we only need to add a load in the collector circuit. Unfortunately it will be "floating" (ungrounded) and if this is a problem, we will connect the load in parallel with the transistor.

The OP's question is about the role of the load (collector) resistance on the transistor mode. Then let's examine our conceptual transistor switch at some typical collector (load) resistance values. To observe the response of the "transistor", we have to connect measuring devices.

**RL = 0 Ω:** We start with the extreme case when the load has zero resistance (short circuit). We apply a constant 1 V voltage to the VCCS input and, as a result, a 1 A current begins flowing through the output loop (the VCCS ratio is 1 S or 1 Ω-1).

As we can see from the *DC live simulation*, the "transistor" manages to push the desired 1 A current through the "load". But how? At what cost? How does it do it? We want to know and not just take it for granted.

[image: schematic]

The explanation is very simple - the output "collector-emitter" part behaves like a resistor with a resistance of 15 Ω. Thus, a voltage of 15 V is applied across it and a current of 1 A flows through it (Ohm's law); the voltage across the zero-resistance load is zero. The transistor is able to do this because it has some resistance; it is "active" as the textbooks say. It is active in the sense that it can change its resistance and thus regulate the current.

**RL = 10 Ω:** CircuitLab has a very handy option to set some internal resistance to be non-zero (for ammeters) and non-infinity (for voltmeters). Let's take advantage of it by replacing the load resistance and the "ideal" ammeter with zero internal resistance with only one real ammeter with 10 Ω resistance.

[image: schematic]

The transistor is still "active" and successfully doing its job of being a current source - to maintain the same 1 A current, it reduces its resistance to 5 Ω so that the total resistance remains 15 Ω. Now the total voltage of 15 V is distributed between the load (10 V) and transistor (5 V).

**RL = 15 Ω:** In an effort to maintain 1 A current, the "transistor" reduces its resistance to zero so that the total resistance remains 15 Ω. It succeeds but is at the limit of its capabilities. As they say in textbooks, the transistor is "saturated". The meaning of this verbal cliché for us is that ***the transistor has exhausted its resistance and has nothing more to reduce***. All supply voltage is applied to the load.

[image: schematic]

Up to this point, the "conceptual transistor" behaves like a "passive" real transistor - it sinks current and its collector voltage is positive.

**RL = 20 Ω:** But if we keep increasing the load resistance more than 15 Ω,   the "transistor" begins producing current and its collector voltage tries to become negative. That is why we have connected the diode D - it turns on and closes the current path through itself. As a result, the voltage across the "transistor" remains zero and the current begins to decrease.

Thus, ***the current of the saturated transistor is determined entirely by the load and not by the transistor*** (in contrast, ***the current of the  transistor in active mode is determined entirely by the transistor and not by the load***).

[image: schematic]

Let's now see this graphically using
the *DC sweep simulation* as the load resistance changes from zero to 20 Ω. As you can see, there is a horizontal part (saturation) after 15 Ω.

[image: STEP 5]

## Exploring a fancy transistor stage

You probably understand that my goal is not only the transistor switch, but the functioning of the transistor in general. In the name of this great goal, let's jump over the limitations of reality and dream a little... because life is too short to allow ourselves to waste our time with boring and meaningless formal "explanations".

**Removing the shunting diode.** So let's imagine that inside our "transistor" there is a built-in voltage source. This is actually the original CircuitLab VCCS, but we just have to remove the diode that we put in at the beginning. As a result, our "transistor" begins behaving very interestingly - in order to maintain the same 1 A current, it adds a 5 V voltage to the 15 V supply voltage! Now it really lives up to its name "active device".

[image: schematic]

Let's now see this graphically using
the *DC sweep simulation* as the load resistance changes from zero to a large value of 1kΩ (as the OP has done). As you can see, there is no horizontal part (saturation) in the curve; the "transistor" is always "active". It manages to maintain the same 1 A current even at the cost of 1 kV voltage. Well, it is a bit difficult to implement this real experiment in practice, but that is why CircuitLab helps us. Everything is possible here and dreams do come true :-)

[image: STEP 6]

**Removing the power supply.** But why do we even need a power supply now that our fancy transistor has it? Let's remove it and see if it makes a difference. It works! The "active transistor" fully powers the load by increasing its voltage to 20 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXEtWd.png)</sup>

The graph is almost the same (the only difference is that the curve begins from zero voltage while above it begins from Vcc).

[image: STEP 7]

## Final conclusions

From the above experiments, we come to the conclusion that ***inside a current source there is a voltage source***. Its voltage (also known as a "compliance voltage") is the maximum voltage that the current source can create across the load with maximum resistance by passing its current through it; the rest of the voltage across the regulated element is zero.

If we increase the load resistance further, the current source needs more voltage to maintain the current but has nowhere to get it from (unless it is made with a "fancy transistor" :-) As a result, ***the current source becomes a "transistor switch"***. So, our final conclusion is:

**The transistor switch is a current source that has reached its compliance voltage.**